# l can't see Ubuntu on my triple-boot menu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-xp, installation

Before installation, I had a dual-boot menu (XP and Win 7, both 32-bits). I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and when I boot the system, I still see my both OS but not Ubuntu.

HD devices are followings:

1. 160 Gb HDD with XP system, 7 system and data partition
2. 1 TB HDD with unused NTFS, data partition and Ubuntu partitions (/home, /, /boot and swap)

Comment: And what bootloader as you using?

Comment: Bootloader ? Cant understand that word.

Comment: A bootloader is the piece of software that allows you to select between many operating systems.  You have to have one installed.  It could be grub, lilo, or many other things.

Comment: Ok probably the one that comes with Ubuntu

Comment: "probably"?  Grub is the default bootloader that is installed with Ubuntu, and it says GNU Grub 1.99 at the very top of the screen when it is up and giving you a choice.  Does that describe the Bootloading screen you see?

Comment: Ubuntu is not part of the choice. I think it is still Windows bootstrapper. Im trying EasyBCD now.

Comment: Found the way via EasyBCD. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Click on the check next to the answer to accept it.  By doing so, we will see that an answer has been accepted as the best answer for your question.  Do not add (solved) to the title.

Answer (score 3):

Download the [free version of EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/), install it within Windows, and use it to edit your current boot menu to include your new Ubuntu installation.

Just scroll down the page a little, and register to get it.

Otherwise, if you **are** seeing the Grub boot menu, then your question should (and probably will) be migrated to the Ask Ubunty exchange, and closed as it is essentially the same as this question here https://askubuntu.com/questions/82928/how-to-make-windows-boot-first and the chosen answer there regarding how to edit your boot menu will also solve your Grub editing issues.

Comment: I have /boot, / /home and swap. Wich one i choose when i edit bootstrapper ?

Comment: Thank you sir. I found the way to see Ubuntu via EasyBCD. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @AlainRoy Don't put **solved** in the title, but please use the green checkmark to **accept Bon Gart's answer**. This will automatically mark this question as solved.